# Highcharts - Changing chart type

Tags: highcharts

I managed to have a chart changing from Pie to Column or Bar, see the jsfiddle below.

I have an issue about the display on xAxis. On the Pie chart, if you uncheck one browser (ex Chrome), then clicking on the Column chart, the column is hide (which is good), but the text on the xAxis for Chrome shows `[object Object]`. How can I hide that as well?

https://jsfiddle.net/quanghuynh/ks8mzc7g/56/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is modified after changing visibility which results in wrong format for categories. As the simplest solution, use `category` axis type instead of setting categories array.

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'category'
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/decfn069/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories